# Finding a particular solution to $y'- \frac{3}{2}y=3t+2e^{t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I given that $y(0)=y_o$ and I have to find the value of $y_o$ that separates solutions that grow positively as $t \rightarrow \infty$ and that grow negatively. How do I that? I already found the general solution and than tried taking the derivative but couldn't think of anything after that.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the fastest-growing term in the general solution involves $e^{3t/2}$.  You want the coefficient of that to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

What did you get for the general solution?  You should look at the coefficient of the exponential term with the highest exponent.  If the coefficient is positive, the solution will grow positively.  If the coefficient is negative, the solution will grow negatively.  That coefficient should involve $y_0$, so set it to zero to find the dividing line.

As an example, if your solution were $y=(y_0+1)e^t+(2-y_0)e^{2t}$ (no relation to the solution to your problem)  you would want the coefficient of $e^{2t}$ to be positive for positive growth, which would require $y_0 \lt 2$

Answer (score 0):

This solution to this equation is $$y(t) = -\frac{2}{3}(2+6e^t+3t)+ce^{3t/2}$$
as you hopefully know already. You are trying to find the [separatrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separatrix_%28dynamical_systems%29) of the system, and since the behavior of $y$ goes as the behavior of it's highest order term, if $c$ is positive it will go to infinity, and if $c$ is negative it will go to negative infinity. Therefore we want $c = 0$, and for this to work we need $y(0)$ to be $-\frac{16}{3}$.